# Linq Query not matching results in DateTimeFormatInfo month list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I can not understand why the following query is not matching results:

I'm currently working using Spanish Culture Info, and using the following string:

```
string input = "newsletter/2015/new-web/newsletter-detalle-marzo/segment-1-3";
```

I can not get the "newsletter-detalle-marzo" using the following linq query:

```
public static string[] GetSegmentMatchingMonth(this string input, string breakPattern = "-") {     

   var query = (from p in input.ToLower().Split('/')
                     where p.Contains(breakPattern) &&
                     DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames.
                     Select(m=>m.ToLower()).Any(m => p.Contains(m.ToLower()))
                     select p).ToArray();
   return query;
}
```

PD: In my current culture the Monthnames are: (string join of Array)

> enero febrero marzo abril mayo junio julio agosto septiembre octubre
>   noviembre diciembre

Output is taking more results with no month name:

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming that 'marzo' does not contain 'newsletter-detail-marzo' (`DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames`...)

Comment: Wait it is reversed. I Update the question

Comment: `m.ToLower()).ToArray()` should be turning the string into an array of `char`s.  What type is MonthNames? A list of string? or a string?

Comment: @ps2goat [`DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) isn't a string.  It's an array of strings.

Comment: @juharr, thanks.  I didn't get a chance to look it up, but the way the OP posted it made it seem like it was a single string.

Comment: If you look at `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames` in your debugger you should see that it has 13 entries.  One of which is an empty string and that is why it always matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change

```
DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames
.Select(m => m.ToLower()).ToArray().Contains(p)
```

to

```
DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames.Any(m => p.EndsWith(m.ToLower()))
```

If the month will always be at the end of that part of the string.  Or you can use `Contains` if it can be anywhere in that part.

**EDIT**

It turns out that `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames` contains one blank string.  So you need to filter that out.

```
DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames
    .Where(m=> m.Length > 0)
    .Select(m=>m.ToLower())
    .Any(m => p.Contains(m))
```

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong previous code in order to protected business related urls and  variables. Updated

Comment: Incredible!!!. Totally true. I did not realize about the blank string!!!!. Its working now! Thanks for you good sight

Comment: @CarlosLanderas I should have read the documentation closer as it says it has an empty string, but didn't notice until I tried your code myself.  I have no idea why it has an empty string and the docs don't explain.

Comment: Real funny resolving this issue. I could not explain myself until I checked as you said. 13 elements in array